# Flipping an image to get mirror effect

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a video processing project which needs some flipping of frame. I tried using cvFlip but doesnt seem to flip along y axis (x axis working...) and results in segmentation fault. Is there any other option??

```
cv::Mat dst=src;      //src= source image from cam
cv::flip(dst, dst, 1);     //segmentation fault shown

imshow("flipped",dst);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code so people can help you fix it.

Comment: How is this related to Qt?

Comment: @Stephen Chu not at all

Comment: I mentioned it becoz I am working with qt and opencv in Qt creator IDe

Answer (score 16):

```
cv::Mat src=imload("bla.png");
cv::Mat dst;               // dst must be a different Mat
cv::flip(src, dst, 1);     // because you can't flip in-place (leads to segfault)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`cv::flip`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#flip) and pass `1` as `flipcode`.

Looking at your edit with the sample code, you cannot flip in place. You need a separate destination `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat dst;
cv::flip(src, dst, 1);
imshow("flipped",dst);
```

Comment: I tried with separate destination as well stil showing  segmentation fault!

Comment: @ranger Actually the documentation seems to imply that the destination array has to be preallocated, for example by doing `dst.create(src.size(),src.type());` . I could not verify if this is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The key is to create the `dst` exactly like the `src`:

```
cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
cv::flip(src, dst, 1);

imshow("flipped", dst);
```

Comment: It is not necessary to set `dst = cv::Mat(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);` the flip function handles that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

At least in openCV 4.8, you can flip in place (with both cv::Mat and cv::UMat).

A possible sample code:

```cpp
// buffer is a pointer to data, for example:
// uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[w*h*4]
// CV_8UC4 means unsigned byte, 4 channel image (for example RGBA)
// UMat allows to use GPU acceleration, it may be useful or not depending
// on the scenario, or you can simply just use cv::Mat.
cv::UMat m = cv::Mat(h , w, CV_8UC4, buffer).getUMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);
// flip accepts a flag that can be 0, <0 or >0
// here I put zero cause if the image is taken in landscape mode, although // looks like it needs vertical mirroring, it is actually horizontal. So you // may want to try the various options if 1 doesn't work as expected
flip(m, m, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, I also think you can flip, and perform other OpenCV mat operations, in place.